# How to setup a refresh_Token call with Hasura and firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, hasura

I have a Hasura server running and firebase-functions. On the frontend I have angular.
I have a working login function that gets the jwt token and the refreshtoken. However I would like to save them in a serverside HttpOnly cookie and make a silent refresh from the client.
This explains the theory of it: https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/
but not the practice.

How do I create such a token in my login function in firebase? And what do I have to set up in Hasura?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the article you mention, explains that the refresh token process is done by having a separate server (outside of Hasura) that handles creating and refreshing the refresh token. On the frontend you constantly hit that server to keep refreshing the jwt and refresh token. This can be done by having a setInterval/setTimeout or (better) using an axios/fetch interceptor on your requests. The idea is to have the jwt and refresh token valid by the time you make the request to Hasura.

Comment: Yeah but what if the user is logged off. So the frontend doesnt refresh the token until his next login. 

Comment: Correct. When a user logs out you delete the token and stop hitting the separate server. The blog post has a section on how to log out a user and a code example. 

“With JWTs, a "logout" is simply deleting the token on the client side so that it can't be used for subsequent API calls.”